# Where does Visual Studio 2008 store the information about a file's character encoding?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, encoding

Somehow VS2008 knows about the character encoding of a source file. I need this information for a tool I wrote in python that does some processing of legacy code (some sophisticated include path remappings etc.), where each file might have a different character encoding. And for processing each file I need to know the character encoding of the file. Where does Visual Studio 2008 store the information about a file's character encoding? Or does it infer this information automatically from the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Options - Text Editor - General, there's a setting "Auto-detect UTF-8 encoding without signature". Maybe that's all there is to it.